# Plotly-Dash Testing in .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline fails with NameError: name 'DashComposite' is not defined

Tags: selenium, gitlab, yaml, pytest, plotly-dash

I had a problem running an integration test for a plotly-dash app I created. I am trying to run an integration test with selenium remote using pytest and Dash Testing (https://dash.plotly.com/testing)

I was able to run an implementation test locally (Windows 10) using the selenium chrome webdriver.

However, it does not work remotely. The gitlab-ci pipeline fails, giving the following error message:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.0, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /builds/jwinter/dash_testing_in_gitlab_ci
plugins: dash-2.0.0
collected 1 item
test_app.py E                                                            [100%]
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
________________________ ERROR at setup of test_example ________________________
request = <SubRequest 'dash_duo' for <Function test_example>>
dash_thread_server = <dash.testing.application_runners.ThreadedRunner object at 0x7f12b8d2a130>
tmpdir = local('/tmp/pytest-of-root/pytest-0/test_example0')
    @pytest.fixture
    def dash_duo(request, dash_thread_server, tmpdir):
>       with DashComposite(
            dash_thread_server,
            browser=request.config.getoption("webdriver"),
            remote=request.config.getoption("remote"),
            remote_url=request.config.getoption("remote_url"),
            headless=request.config.getoption("headless"),
            options=request.config.hook.pytest_setup_options(),
            download_path=tmpdir.mkdir("download").strpath,
            percy_assets_root=request.config.getoption("percy_assets"),
            percy_finalize=request.config.getoption("nopercyfinalize"),
            pause=request.config.getoption("pause"),
        ) as dc:
E       NameError: name 'DashComposite' is not defined
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dash/testing/plugin.py:141: NameError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_app.py::test_example - NameError: name 'DashComposite' is not defined
=============================== 1 error in 0.09s ===============================
```

I created a minimum example based on the example app on https://dash.plotly.com/layout.
It fails with the given error message.

**app.py**
Based on https://dash.plotly.com/layout example

```py
from dash import dcc, html
import dash
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({
   "Fruit": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas"],
   "Amount": [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
   "City": ["SF", "SF", "SF", "Montreal", "Montreal", "Montreal"]
})

fig = px.bar(df, x="Fruit", y="Amount", color="City", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
   html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

   html.Div(children='''
       Dash: A web application framework for your data.
   '''),

   dcc.Graph(
       id='example-graph',
       figure=fig
   )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```py
stages:
  - test
test:dashboard:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.8.0
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome :latest
  before_script:
    - pip install -r requirements_for_testing.txt
    - pip install pytest
  script: |
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD
    pytest
```

**conftest.py**

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def pytest_setup_options():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    return options
```

**test_app.py**

```py
from dash.testing.application_runners import import_app
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions


def test_example(dash_duo):
    app = import_app(
        app_file='app')
    dash_duo.start_server(app)
    WebDriverWait(dash_duo.driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#example-graph")))
    assert dash_duo.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
        "#example-graph").is_displayed()
```

**requirements_for_testing.txt**

```
dash >= 2.0.0
dash[testing]
pytest
selenium
pandas
plotly
requests
```

**What I tried**

I tried to include selenium/standalone-chrome as I found it in [Running plotly dash selenium tests in gitlab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232458/running-plotly-dash-selenium-tests-in-gitlab-ci)
But no matter if I added

```py
services:
 - selenium/standalone-chrome : latest
```

or

```py
services:
 - selenium__standalone-chrome : latest
```

or deleted the services section in gitlab-ci.yml completely,
nothing changed.

Thank you so much for considering my question. I was not able to find anything on this DashComposite error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and I think I found the reason. The `DashComposite` (and testing of Dash apps in general) will require the `dash[testing]` to be installed. That is, the `dash` package with the `testing` extras.

I see that you have the `dash[testing]` listed in your `requirements_for_testing.txt`, which you use in your `gitlab-ci.yml`. Now it appears that there is a *bug in `pip`* (`20.2.1` and others) discussed for example [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4957) which makes `pip` *not*  install `somepackage[extras]` if you have already `somepackage` installed.

### Fixing problems with pip

To fix the problems with pip, you want to use the `--use-feature 2020-resolver` option. In your case, instead of

```
pip install -r requirements_for_testing.txt
```

you would use

```
pip install -r requirements_for_testing.txt --use-feature 2020-resolver
```

in the `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Another option is to use newer pip version, that has the 2020 resolver as default. Looking from [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) and [here](https://blog.python.org/2020/11/pip-20-3-release-new-resolver.html) it seems that from `pip 20.3` onwards the new dependency resolver is the default. To update pip to the newest version, you would run

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```